# What can I do for 'Injection Bundle Build Error'?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm building a native ios application using XCode 6.6.1 on Yosemite 10.10.1.
Also using Injection for XCode(http://injectionforxcode.com/)

I got an error when I run Inject Source(^=) says:

Disconnected from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1800BDFA-4053-4093-95C3-F38CAA261360/data/Containers/Data/Application/619B38FB-E7E0-4BC1-AF48-99DC55576993
at /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/InjectionPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/common.pm line 51.
main::error(‘Build Failed with status: 65. You may need to open and edit t…’) called at /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/InjectionPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/injectSource.pl line 386

I've recognized:
Connected to "Injection" plugin, ready to load x86_64 code.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ:

> **I get errors when Injection tries to build it's bundle. Whats up?**
>
> When converting a class to inject the source needs to be able to
>   compile in a separate "InjectionBundle" project in a different
>   directory than it is usually compiled. You may have to adjust the
>   include path or Frameworks in the project in the bundle project for it
>   to build cleanly. Once a project is setup the InjectionBundle
>   sub-project can be placed in source control and shared with other
>   developers.

http://injectionforxcode.johnholdsworth.com/faq.html

Unless you know which file it is unable to find, you can set the project directory to be recursively searched in the framework search paths build setting (I would reset it back when done).

[image: something like this]

Apart from this, make sure you are editing the file you'd like injection to work from.

[image]

Comment: Gurpartap Singh,
I know where all frameworks are.
I've tried your suggestion but doesn't work.
thank you for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error with OS X project:

`warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/nater/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-project-cfewqrudvqrwzqgnqhnibmvyserw/Build/Products/Debug-macosx'
framework not found for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
*** Build Failed with status: 65. You may need to open and edit the bundle project to resolve issues with either header include paths or Frameworks the bundle links against. ***`

After understanding how the injection works and looking at the compile warning, it was obvious that the bundle was looking at the wrong path.

To note, `don't try to edit` the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` from the bundle project build settings. A script sets this at build-time. You could add the framework path, but I didn't want to do this for every injected project.

**Solution:**

> I was able to resolve this by modifying the plugin `InjectSource.pl` script file. I removed `macosx` and the `-` that follows after the `Debug` folder name. I ran inject source command and `it works`.

Plugin should be found with the following path: `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/InjectionPlugin.xcplugin`

It's simple error, but hope to help anyone else.

This should be probably on a different thread, but I'll add it here since the title.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Unfortunately I no longer develop with the same environment. So I can not evaluate whether it's correct.
However it's important keeping how you solved. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks. It's no worries. This solution may not have worked for you, but could have helped someone else. It's another potential solution someone can explore.